# Empty ctx._source variable when running script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

In elasticsearch head I run query for retriving some aggregations. To do it, I need to get some infos from ctx variable. In my script when I try to use: 
ctx._source I get nullPointerException.

```
"aggregations": {
    "fieldId": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "... <Here I want to get ctx._source but I get null pointer>... ,
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The special `ctx` variables is only available during indexation ( ingest processor, update_by_query etc... ).

For more information about painless script context and available variable you can go [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-contexts.html).

I don't think the source is available during aggregation since it would for elastic to all sources of documents before making the aggregations. That would have a huge overhead. You can only rely on doc_values to create the scripted value.